# Flutter, How to make my raw material buttons large and more tightly packed together.

Tags: dart, flutter

I have some code that creates 7 Raw Material Buttons in the shape of a circle. However I cannot seem to change the size of the circle, or position them closer together.

**Page.dart**

```
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    new ThemeButton(Colors.red, () => print("red")),
    new ThemeButton(Colors.orange, () => print("orange")),
    new ThemeButton(Colors.yellow, () => print("yellow")),
    new ThemeButton(Colors.green, () => print("green")),
    new ThemeButton(Colors.blue, () => print("blue")),
    new ThemeButton(Colors.indigo, () => print("pink")),
    new ThemeButton(Colors.purple, () => print("purple")),
  ],
),
```

**ThemeButton.dart**

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return RawMaterialButton (
    shape: CircleBorder(),
    fillColor: _themeColour,
    elevation: 0.0,
    highlightElevation: 0.0,
    onPressed: () => _onPressed(),
    splashColor: Colors.transparent,  
    highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
  );
}
```

**Display:**

[image]

So the three issue I am facing are all around the size and positioning on the element.

1. The Circles are too small for my liking.
2. The space around the circles are too wide.
3. I can click outside the circle and it will still register the click.

I have looked at the arguments for the Raw Material Button and cannot see what I can change. Adding a padding widget and setting it to 0 doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/RawMaterialButton-class.html) for `RawMaterialButton`, there should be a `padding` property that you can set in the constructor, which is typical for this type of component. Try updating the padding value in the constructor of the button instead of adding a new Widget. To be clear, trying setting `padding` to `EdgeInsets.all(0.0)`.

For further sizing, you can start to look at the `Row` [class properties](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html), specifically `MainAxisSize`, or wrapping them in variations of the `Flexible` Widget family.

Answer (score 8):

Changing the padding property, unfortunately, did not work for me. However, changing the constraints parameter like in this example turned out to be quite effective:

```
RawMaterialButton(
    constraints: BoxConstraints.tight(Size(36, 36)),
    onPressed: null,
    child: Icon(Icons.trending_up, size: 18),
    shape: new CircleBorder(),
    elevation: 0.0,
    fillColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 240, 240, 240),
),
```

Hope it helps!